# Why do Markov matrices converge to the same vector after infinite steps irrespective of the starting vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

Can anyone explain me the reason why does any probability vector U<sub>0</sub> converge to the same vector U<sub>infinity</sub> when a Markov matrix is acted on it?
I don't know how to put this but let me try.
If x<sub>1</sub> and x<sub>2</sub> are two Eigenvectors and the Eigenvalues are 1 and 0.75.

In the equation
U<sub>0</sub> = C<sub>1</sub>  x<sub>1</sub> + C<sub>2</sub>  x<sub>2</sub>
Why do I get the same value of C<sub>1</sub> irrespective of any probability vector U<sub>0</sub> to converge to the same steady state?. Hope this makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Each time you multiply by the markov matrix, the x1 component is left alone while the x2 component shrinks by a factor of 3/4, which eventually removes it.

Comment: Also, the x1 component turns out to be never zero for any initial probability vector. This is because it turns out that only the x1 eigenvector can be made into a probability vector; the other eigenvectors turn out to sum to zero, because they are orthogonal to the right eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$, which is the vector of $1$s. This is important, because without this property, it could happen that your limiting vector was just zero instead of the expected $U_\infty$.

Comment: F Scott FItzgerald had a nice summary: "So we beat on, boats against the current, borne back ceaselessly into the past." The markov matrix sets up a flow on the space of all vectors, and that flow sweeps (almost) everything eventually onto a path that heads for a single point (which Fitzgerald would call "the past").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Ian’s comments, you can view the action of a matrix on a vector in the following way: if $\mathbf v$ is an eigenvector of the matrix with eigenvalue $\lambda$, then multiplying a vector $w$ by the matrix multiplies the component of $w$ in the $v$-direction by $\lambda$. For a stochastic matrix, $|\lambda|\le1$, so repeated applications of the matrix will cause the components of the initial probability vector that are in the directions with $|\lambda|\lt1$ to shrink away. What’s left will be the components in directions where the eigenvalue is $\pm1$. For the simple type of Markov chain under consideration, the eigenspace is one-dimensional (and we won’t have $\lambda=-1$), so we’ll be left with the steady-state vector.

To see why the last statement might hold, consider the $2\times2$ case. We have $$P=\pmatrix{p&1-p\\q&1-q}$$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$ and $\lambda_2=p-q$. Observe that $|\lambda_2|\lt1$ unless $p=0$ and $q=1$ or vice-versa. The corresponding eigenvectors are $\mathbf v_1=\left({q\over1-p+q},{1-p\over1-p+q}\right)$ and $\mathbf v_2=(-1,1)$. (We’ve normalized $v_1$ so that its components sum to $1$.) Now, any probability vector $\mathbf v$ lies on the line segment joining $(1,0)$ to $(0,1)$, so it can be written in the form $\mathbf v=\mathbf v_1+\alpha\mathbf v_2$, so $P^n\mathbf v=\mathbf v_1+\lambda_2^n\alpha\mathbf v_2$, which clearly converges to $\mathbf v_1$ as $n\to\infty$.

The situation is similar for larger state spaces: probability vectors lie on the hyperplane $\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf 1=1$, and we can choose eigenvectors of $1$ which lie on this hyperplane. Any initial probability vector can be written as a linear combination of eigenvectors, and under repeated application of $P$ the components corresponding to $|\lambda|\lt1$ will “fade away,” leaving only the components for which $|\lambda|=1$.