# Why does a system tend to go to a stable distribution if it has an eigenvalue of 1?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm learning about eigenvalues and eigenvectors and my book states that if the dominant eigenvalue of the system is 1 then the the system approaches a steady stable state but it doesn't go into detail on why. Why does that happen?

Comment: You might find [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2032075/265466) helpful. On the surface it’s about Markov chains, but the description of long-term behavior of powers of a matrix is applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a sufficient condition. Consider a random walk on the edges of a cube, in which at every second you go from a vertex to an adjacent vertex with probability $\frac{1}{3}$. $1$ is an eigenvalue of the transition matrix, but if at time $0$ we are with probability $1$ at some vertex, a steady distribution is never reached, because our random walk is on a bipartite graph. Or we may be in the case of a random walk on a graph made by $n\geq 2$ connected components, with the eigenvalue $1$ being dominant but with multiplicity greater than one: in such a case a steady state is reached, but it depends on the original distribution.

A correct statement (involving irreducible, aperiodic matrices) is given by the classical [Perron-Frobenius theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem).