# Initial state of a Markov Process

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, abstract-algebra, statistics

Intuitively (without using matrices) , why in a Markov process the probability vector , after a huge number of iterations, is indipendent from the initial probability vector ?

**(Im considering the particular case in which this happens)**

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2032075/why-do-markov-matrices-converge-to-the-same-vector-after-infinite-steps-irrespec/2032249#2032249.

Comment: Saying *"I'm considering the particular case in which this happens"* is close to saying *"why is it true when it is true?"* to which the answer is *"because in those cases it is true"*.  A better question might be asking why a  positive-recurrent irreducible aperiodic Markov Chain has a limiting distribution and why that distribution is unique

Answer (score 3):

**Intuitively:** If a Markov process has a limiting distribution (which is the  "probability vector after a huge number of iterations [that is] independent from the initial probability vector that you mention), that means the process will reach a kind of equilibrium over time. For example, consider a marathon runner that reaches a steady marathon pace as the race goes on, regardless of the speed of her initial sprint. Recall that a Markov process has the property that *the future, given the present, is independent of the past.* So very loosely speaking, if the present time is "far enough along" (i.e. "after a huge number of iterations" as you say), then the initial state, which is part of the distant past, "washes out."

**Warning:** *Not every Markov process has a limiting distribution*, let alone a unique one. The limiting distribution But of course, we need a rigorous characterization of "huge number of iterations," so we use limits.

**The technical details:** Suppose we have a Markov chain $\{X_n\}$ with states $\{1, 2, \dots, m\}$. Then the limiting distribution is a probability vector $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ such that

$$\boldsymbol{\pi} = (\pi_1, \pi_2, \dots, \pi_m) = \Big(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mathbb P(X_n = 1), \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(X_n = 2), \dots, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb P(X_n = m)\Big).$$

An irreducible and aperiodic Markov chain on a finite state space $S$ has a unique limiting distribution $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ that can be obtained by solving the system of linear equations $\sum_{i \in S} \pi_i = 1$ and $\boldsymbol{\pi} = \boldsymbol{\pi} \boldsymbol{P}$, where $\boldsymbol{P}$ is the probability transition matrix of the Markov chain.

But if a Markov chain is *periodic*, limiting distributions are not guaranteed (i.e. the theorem above does not hold if the aperiodicity assumption is relaxed). It is easy to check that a Markov chain on $\{0,1\}$ with probability transition matrix given below cannot have a limiting distribution.

$$\boldsymbol{P} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You might check whether you want to say *periodic* in *"But if a Markov chain is aperiodic, it does not have a limiting distribution"*

Comment: It actually can have a limiting distribution in the periodic case, but now whether it does or not depends on the initial distribution. This dependence can be nontrivial (i.e. it can happen that there are non-stationary choices of the initial distribution that converge to a stationary distribution even though other initial distributions do not ).

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Incorporated both. Typo fixed and more accurately qualified the example in my post.